# How to match any URL with HttpTestingController.expectOne?

Tags: angular, unit-testing

`expectOne()` requires a URL string to match the request that the code under test makes via `HttpClient`. But, I want separate tests for verifying the request URL and verifying the result data. I want one test to verify the request URL -- ignoring the result data -- which I can write. And I want another test to verify the result data -- regardless of the URL -- which I cannot write since `expectOne` requires the URL parameter to match.

I searched for a way to tell `expectOne` to ignore the URL or to match any URL, but found nothing. I did try passing `'*'`, but that didn't work.

Is there a way to get `HttpTestingController` to match any URL?

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';

import { OperationsLogService } from './operations-log.service';
import { Severity } from './severity.enum';

describe('OperationsLogService', () => {
    let service: OperationsLogService;
    let httpMock: HttpTestingController;

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [
                HttpClientTestingModule
            ],
            providers: [
                OperationsLogService
            ]
        });

        service = TestBed.get(OperationsLogService);
        httpMock = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
    });
    it('requests by page and max-count', (done) => {
        service
            .getEntries(3, 5)
            .subscribe((res: any) => {
                done();
            });
        const request = httpMock.expectOne('api/operations-log/oplog.json?page=3&max-count=5');
        request.flush({});
        httpMock.verify();
    });
    it('provides entries', (done) => {
        const entries = [
            {
                severity: Severity.Informational,
                whenLogged: Date.now(),
                code: 123,
                message: 'msg'
            }
        ];
        service
            .getEntries(3, 5)
            .subscribe((res: any) => {
                expect(res).toEqual(entries);
                done();
            });
        // don't want to specify the URL here
        const request = httpMock.expectOne('api/operations-log/oplog.json?page=3&max-count=5');
        request.flush(entries);
        httpMock.verify();
    });
});
```

Why I want this capability: Tests should be independent of each other. One issue/change should cause as few tests to fail as possible. If the URL test fails, then I don't want the other test (provides entries) to fail. One suggested that I store the URL in a common variable. That does eliminate code duplication, but the tests are still weak. If one fails (due to the URL changing), they both will fail.

Comment: can't you just put the url in the variable and pass it to expectOne() in both tests? Not sure what is the problem you're trying to solve here, as you have one test for url an another for data.

Comment: @Mac_W: I agree that your suggestion makes the tests work. And, for a small number of tests (as in my example) it's fine. But, consider having _many_ tests. In general, a test should not verify too much. When over-specified, one change will cause many tests to file. Better that the minimum number of tests fail for any specific change. I don't want every test to verify the URL, because changing the URL would cause every test to fail, but the tests that verify the logic should not fail -- should not depend on the URL.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is an overload to `expectOne()` that will do what you need (see the documentation at https://angular.io/api/common/http/testing/HttpTestingController#expectone):

```
abstract expectOne(matchFn: ((req: HttpRequest<any>) => boolean), description?: string): TestRequest
```

So for your test to match any URL, just return `true` for every call to the match predicate:

```
const request = httpMock.expectOne(() => true);
request.flush(entries);
```

Comment: Thanks, ```() => true``` is a much cleaner solution and one can avoid having all kind of URLs in the spec file.